# Using angular ui-sortable and angularfire is there a way to save the new order to the database when sorting?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to use ui-sortable to sort a list and then save the new list order to firebase using angularfire so that when I refresh it maintains the proper order. Can that be achieved?

Here's the relevant code:

//html

```
<div ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="andreyTasks">
  <div ng-repeat="task in andreyTasks"></div>
</div>
```

//controller

```
    $scope.sortableOptions = {
    axis: 'y',
    stop: function( event, ui ) {
      //save the new sort order
    }
  };
```

Comment: Does ui-sortable offer any event notifications? If so, just tie andreyTasks.$save() into the event?

Comment: "update" and "stop" both let me run functions that trigger on events but andreyTasks.$save() has no effect.

Comment: If andreyTasks is an array, you'll need to call it on specific elements. You'll need to provide more context for more specific help.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Could you find any answers? Thanks

Comment: I never did figure it out but hopefully I am a bit more experienced now. I eventually do need to implement this feature and will try again in the next week or so.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked something together that is working -- not very elegant.

So, if I have a todo list (firebaseArray).. where the add looks like this:

```
$scope.todos.$add({

            simpleDesc : desc,

            list: []

                ,

            toggle:false,
            optionMenu:false,
            taskCount:0,
            doneCount:0,
            priority: -1

    })
```

Then, in my sortable options I have:

```
$scope.sortableOptions = {
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $scope.todos.forEach(function(todo){
            todo.priority = $scope.todos.indexOf(todo);
            $scope.todos.$save(todo);
    });
   }
}
```

The relevant front end components look like this:

```
<div class="row" ng-model = "todos" ui-sortable="sortableOptions" >
  <div class="input-group" ng-repeat = "todo in todos |orderBy:  'priority' " > .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just added a firebase ui-sortable integration example in [ui-sortable's README](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/README.md#integrations), based on the great code example noted in [firebase/angularfire#687](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/issues/687).